# How to prevent memory leak in android?

Tags: android, optimization

I started a few months ago to program in android doing my first app that consists of taking orders like a waiters app.

As it was the first app you can imagine that i wasn't aiming for the optimization but that was a big mistake. I've deployed app in some restaurants and till this moment all was going well.

**The issue:**

Now the app was installed in a restaurant where they take a lot of orders for a single table they can get up to 10 minutes where they take orders and yesterday i've got a call where they said that the app was crashing on tables with a lot of people.

Now i'm trying to simulate what happened in my company.

**The App:**

The app consist of the Main screen where the user can choose to enter in settings or in the orders then there is another "login" activity and then the "main" where there is an alert that asks for the number of table then the waiter takes order and send it.
After sending i'm just "resetting" the activity or better by clearing the recyclerView out of items and settings all values to 0 but i think that it's produce a "little" memory leak.

**Conclusion:**

Now i would have as more as possible suggestions on how can i improve my app performance or better how could i prevent memory leak or even if it's possible to "recreate" the activity in someway after the waiters send the receipt so i could "save" some memory or idk.

Actually here is a screen of profiling, i don't know it it's could help

[image]

Comment: I'm only saying that in a jokingly manner; I don't think you know how to use TL;DR

Comment: @NikosHidalgo it doesn't indicate like a summary? anyway it's better that i cancel it at this point lol

Comment: It literally means Too Long; Didn't Read and it's used at the end of long texts to summarize the text. In your case, it was used to summarize the omitted part of your story and not the actual problem you're describing. Again, I was just making a funny observation, please don't be offended!

Comment: @NikosHidalgo that's fine, now i know what TL;DR mean's

Comment: When it comes to your problem, I think you need to provide some of the relevant code, otherwise be prepared for people downvoting your question and regarding in as too broad

Answer (score 4):

Good practices to avoid memory leaks IMHO:

- avoid storing android context **statically** in helper or data classes
- remember to **unregister broadcast receivers** once their job it's finished. A good practice is to register inside onResume() method and unregister inside onPause() method
- prefer the usage of LiveData for your "model" classes
- use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library to detect any potential leak
- be **careful** with the usage of **static variables**, remember to set them to null once are no longer useful to the application, that way they would be eligible to be garbage collected.

You can find an interesting [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/9-ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-android-b6d81648e35e) about this topic on Medium

Answer (score 3):

First of all you seem to not have a `CrashReport` library on your app. So first thing to do is to add [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA14TjBRD_ARIsAOCmO9YrSo_5LYhpYlxAMasOQPWf7VAdrEgNM48t8T6wRnkro4tb5GbAZFQaApS8EALw_wcB) to your app.

> Get clear, actionable insight into app issues with this powerful crash reporting solution for Android

Then if you think you have leaks on your app, I suggest you use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

> A memory leak detection library for Android and Java.

Once `Crashlytics` in place you will know where the issue comes from. It can give you as far as the line of code that crashes your app.

Comment: Actually i've yet heard about Crashlytics but can i use it even if i doesn't use firebase as DB? does it work without the firebase authentication?

Comment: Yes you can use Crashlytics alone

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any subscribers to events which is not unsubscribed? This is a common pitfall for memory leaks. I suggest that you use a memory profiler to profile the memory usage. This article gives you an introduction if you are using android studio:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by the others, without specifics, it is hard to know what is the cause of the memory leak.
I wrote apps for Android tablet at restaurants in Beijing (Lily's American Diners), and I struggled with leaks for a long time. The problem is you have tablets Android tablets running for 14 hours a day so you have to have very robust architecture so things do leak and get torn down by the OS.
1) Canaryleak and Crashylytics are good ideas. I used ACRA.
2) Try to avoid popups, global variables, all the obvious things.
3) I use a background service to handle uploading data to the server, downloading menus from the server, printing to POS printers.
4) For network operations, use OKHTTP, it makes all the Async network operations cleaner.
5) For image loading, use Square Picasso. it makes all the image cashing cleaner.
6) In your lifecycle architecture,minimize activities. I use 1 single instance activity for the splash screen initial load and 1 single instance activity if they choose to do the manager operations, setttings, etc., then, there is 1 activity that runs the whole day long and handles everything. Within that activity, I use a ViewFlipper to quickly change "pages" (views) for each of the following operations:
a) choosing items from the menu
b) showing the ticket of selected items
c) showing large pics of the dish or special options for each dish
d) showing a successful sent order
e) showing an unsuccessfully sent order
f) showing the choose table screen for customers or waiters, whoever does it.
g) showing daily specials
The other big issue is persistent storage so orders and menus don't get lost, etc during the long running operation of these kinds of apps. i made extensive use of shared preferences.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different possibilities, for example:

1. Database remains opened
2. Data cannot encapsulate properly.
3. From Shared Preference

These are common possibilities from where the data may leak.

Comment: Actually i'm sure that the database is closed as i just use it in the settings to populate the database with all plates and user's of the restaurant while in sharedpreference i just store the settings preferences so i don't think it may leak

Comment: The data of receipts are not stored on the device they are sent to a server and when i open again the table i'm going to redownload them via Ion library

Comment: Use garbageCollection methods  that will free the memory. From static variables also have some memory leaks.